# Should ASPX code-behind be within a namespace?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, coding-style, namespaces

Something like this:

```
Namespace Test_NS
    Partial Class Test_WebSite
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Or should I leave it alone and only keep the classes in my App_Code under a Namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes little difference for a project.  By default, your code-behind is NOT in a shared name-space.  Also, your classes (I assume you're still talking code-behind) are not stored in the app_code folder.

Do you use visual studio?  It will do the organizing for you, and if you're not sure, then I'd just leave everything as-is.

Any new .vb files (not code-behind) that you create independently do go in the app_code folder, and you can group these in name-spaces (or not) as you wish.

Comment: Well any classes (code-behind) outside of the ASPX I let VS put in the App_Code folder, but I put those under a Namespace. The ASPX code-behind I was wondering if it best or even good practice to put that under a namespace or just leave as is.

Comment: Yes -- that's what I mean -- leave as-is.  You can decide to customize your code-behind files by combining them into a single namespace if you want, but then you'll also have to customize the page directive on each aspx page.  Also, it will affect your publishing / compiling experience a bit.  I wouldn't say you can't combine your code-behind into a single name-space, but it seems like more work, so unless you have a good reason to do it, why would you want to?

Comment: As far as ASPX code behind, I have no reason. I was just wondering if it was common, good practice or best practice to do so. That's all. Thanks!